# is there a way to access the screen height and width in initstate flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to preload my images and declare once in initstate

**Example:**

```
late List<String> _assetBg;
  late List<Image> _imagesBg;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _assetBg = ['assets/images/1.jpg',
      'assets/images/2.jpg',
      'assets/images/3.jpg',
      'assets/images/4.jpg'];

    _imagesBg = _initializeListImage(context, _assetBg);
          
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      _tombolRenderBox =
          _tombolKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    });
  }
```

**the problem is :**

```
List<Image> _initializeListImage (BuildContext context,List<String> assets){
    List<Image> result = [];
    for (var asset in assets) {
      result.add(
          Image(
            image: AssetImage(asset),
            ///Problem is here :
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 2,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,

          )
      );
    }
    return result;
  }
```

**and prereload here :**

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _prechaceImage(context, _imagesBg);
  }

void _prechaceImage(BuildContext context, List<Image> images){
    for(var image in images){
      precacheImage(image.image, context);
    }
  }
```

But this gives me an error

**error :**

`dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _IntroScreenState.initState() completed.`

is there a way to work around this? i really need to calculate screen width to animate rotation of my widget, thanks for help.

Comment: You can try adding `_imagesBg = _initializeListImage(context, _assetBg);` inside `addPostFrameCallback`

Comment: thanks for your comment, if i put there give me another error : `LateInitializationError: Field '_imagesBg' has not been initialized.` .

Comment: is this the first screen? because if not, you can try to send the height and wight value from parameter

Comment: @esentis i did your suggest assign `_listImages` with empty list, and initialize in post frame callback, its work, but if feel like hack somehow, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `window` from `dart:ui` package:

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

// Screen size in density independent pixels
var screenWidth = (window.physicalSize.shortestSide / window.devicePixelRatio);
var screenHeight = (window.physicalSize.longestSide / window.devicePixelRatio);

// Screen size in real pixels
var screenWidthPixels = window.physicalSize.shortestSide;
var screenHeightPixels = window.physicalSize.longestSide;
```

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/window.html

Comment: 'window' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Look up the current FlutterView from the context via View.of(context) or consult the PlatformDispatcher directly instead. Deprecated to prepare for the upcoming multi-window support. This feature was deprecated after v3.7.0-32.0.pre.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

Comment: @OverdoseB12 this question is specifically asked for usage in `initState`, when context is not available

Comment: I know but that is the exact message I get when trying to paste the code inside my ```initState``` of my Widget.

Comment: @OverdoseB12 you can safely ignore that message, unless you are going to actually support multi-window

Answer (score 4):

`window.physicalSize` is deprecated and will be removed in future version.

You can use [`PlatformDispatcher`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PlatformDispatcher/instance.html)

```dart
  final view = PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first;
  print(view.physicalSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing answers from other users (considering that `window` is deprecated), you can use:

```dart
double get screenPixelRatio => PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.devicePixelRatio;

// Screen size in real pixels
double get screenWidthPixels => PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize.shortestSide;
double get screenHeightPixels => PlatformDispatcher.instance.views.first.physicalSize.longestSide;

// Screen size in density independent pixels
double get screenWidth => (screenWidthPixels / screenPixelRatio);
double get screenHeight => (screenHeightPixels / screenPixelRatio);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can save value in common class

```
class ScreenSize {
   static double width;
   static double height;
}
```

And in build method of splash screen or main.dart

```
ScreenSize.width = Mediaquery.of(context).size.width;
ScreenSize.height= Mediaquery.of(context).size.height;
```

You can use it any screen of app, I hope this will be helpful

Comment: `initState` runs before `build`, so you can't use it before assigning it